# Add "My Ordes" to My Account Navigation

Tags: navigation

I would link to add a link to Order History in my top.links menu .
I add this code in my local.xml:

```
 <reference name="top.links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>orders</name><path>sales/order/history/</path><label>My Orders</label></action>       
</reference>
```

But every time i click on "Order link" the path is added to the url so I have someting link : site.com/customer/sales/order/history and then site.com/customer/sales/order/history/sales/order/history. 
What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it same way Magento doing for other top links

for example,

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
```

You will need to create one function in helper class with return order history url,

I did it in `Mage_Customer_Helper_Data` and added my function as below

```
public function getOrderHistoryUrl()
{
    return $this->_getUrl('sales/order/history');
}
```

Now you can used this function in xml same as it was in my account link, so it should be like

```
<reference name="top.links">
      <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><label>Orders</label><url helper="customer/getOrderHistoryUrl"/><title>My Orders</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>50</position></action>
</reference>
```

you can extend the helper class or you can do it with your own custom helper class and module.

Comment: You shouldn't need to overwrite/add to core files. If you did want to add a helper you should do it in your own module. You can still use ` `<action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>orders</name><path>sales/order/history/</path><label>My Orders</label></action>`

Comment: i've got some problem with extend sales helper. I've create another ask here [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88541/extend-mage-sales-helper-data-doesnt-work). This method work properly if i make a copy of the original file (Thanks Akhilesh Patel!!) but i don't like to copy all the file.. I would like to extend the helper class...