# Extend Mage_Sales_Helper_Data doesn't work

Tags: magento-1.9, helper, toplinks, extend, history

I would like to add a function in Mage_Sales_Helper_Data without editing or copy of the original file. So I try to extend it, but this code doesn't work

I have created a config.xml in this folder app\code\local\ML\etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
       <ML_Sales>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
       </ML_Sales>
   </modules>
   <global>
      <helpers>
       <sales>
         <rewrite>
           <data>ML_Sales_Helper_Data</data>
         </rewrite>
        </sales>
      </helpers>
   </global>
</config>
```

And then in app\code\local\ML\Sales\Helper I have created Data.php

```
<?php 
require_once('Mage/Sales/Helper/Data.php'); 
class ML_Sales_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Data {
    public function getOrderHistoryUrl()
    {
        return $this-> _getUrl('sales/order/history');

    }  

}
?>
```

Finally into my `app\design\frontend\my_package\default\layout\local.xml` I wrote this code for get the link of  "My Order" on  my account navigation

```
 <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales">
                <label>Orders</label>
                <url helper="sales/getOrderHistoryUrl"/>
                <title>My Orders</title><prepare/>
                <urlParams/>
                <position>50</position>
            </action>        
</reference>
```

and also in app\etc\modules

```
 <ML_Sales>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
     </ML_Sales>
```

What is wrong? Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all declare the helper for your module in config.xml as below

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <ml_sales>
            <class>ML_Sales_Helper</class>
        </ml_sales>
        <sales>
            <rewrite>
                <data>ML_Sales_Helper_Data</data>
            </rewrite>
        </sales>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

Now in your app\code\local\ML\Sales\Helper\Data.php the content goes like this

```
<?php 
class ML_Sales_Helper_Data extends Mage_Sales_Helper_Data {
    public function getOrderHistoryUrl()
    {
        echo 'hello'; exit;
        return $this-> _getUrl('sales/order/history');

    }  

}
?>
```

in your app\design\frontend\my_package\default\layout\local.xml

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="ml_sales">
        <label>Orders</label>
        <url helper="ml_sales/getOrderHistoryUrl"/>
        <title>My Orders</title>
        <prepare/>
        <urlParams/>
        <position>50</position>
    </action>        
</reference>
```

after doing this clear the cache and check

Note:- Please check in the xml file there should not be any spaces in the xml file.otherwise this will give error.

Comment: this give me a Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Ml_Sales_Helper_Data' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\italianamacchi\app\Mage.php on line 547

Comment: clear the cache and check

Comment: delete cache folder from the var/ folder

Comment: I do it, but i get anyway the error

Comment: Mage_Ml_Sales_Helper_Data its ML or MI ?

Comment: Ml with a lowercase l .. but I usually use uppercase

Comment: yor folder structure of ur module is app\code\local\ML or app\code\local\MI ?

Comment: app\code\local\ML

Comment: code throws error as Mage_Ml_Sales_Helper_Data please check somewere thr is a typo error of MI instead of ML

Comment: this work!! before i have my etc folder on my ML folder. Now I put it into my ML/Sales how Akhilesh Patel suggestion.
Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need this line in your helper `require_once('Mage/Sales/Helper/Data.php');`. The class will be autoloaded.

Also, your new class should extend the original helper

```
 class ML_Sales_Helper_Data extends Mage_Sales_Helper_Data
```

And remember to add the `app/etc/modules/ML_Sales.xml` file that tells magento to pick up your module

Comment: I've add the code of my app/etc/modules/ML_Sales.xml and make the change you suggested but nothing is changed... :(

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Comment: yes on magento is disabled and i cleared also the browser cahce but nothing...

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps and it should work

**1. app/code/local/ML/Sales/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <ML_Sales>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </ML_Sales>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <sales>
                <class>ML_Sales_Helper</class>
            </sales>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <data>ML_Sales_Helper_Sales_Data</data>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

**2. app/code/local/ML/Sales/Helper/Data.php**

```
<?php
class ML_Sales_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

**3. app/code/local/ML/Sales/Helper/Sales/Data.php**

```
<?php
class ML_Sales_Helper_Sales_Data extends Mage_Sales_Helper_Data
{
    protected function getOrderHistoryUrl()
    {
        return $this-> _getUrl('sales/order/history');
    }  
}
```

**4. app/etc/modules/ML_Sales.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <ML_Sales>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </ML_Sales>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Same  Fatal error: Class 'Mage_ML_Sales_Helper_Data' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\italianamacchi\app\Mage.php on line 547
but with ML(uppercase) of the Pradeep Sanku answer